# Set tray icon to always display?

Tags: c++, tray

I wrote a demo with C++. It's function: to create a tray icon in the Windows 7 toolbar. But the Windows 7 toolbar has two places, hide or show.  In the control panel we can change the notification setting to show or hide.  How can I control the place of tray icon display with C++ ?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't do it. Why do you think an user would like to have his notification preferences hijacked by an application which thinks itself to be so very special?

Comment: @NathanOliver because i need this demo do it. can you help me solve this problem? i think if i can read control panel settings ,i can get the setting record, so that i can modify it

Comment: It's not possible quote: *When an icon is added to the notification area on Windows 7, it is added to the overflow section of the notification area by default. This area contains notification area icons that are active, but not visible in the notification area. **Only the user can promote an icon from the overflow to the notification area**, although in certain circumstances the system can temporarily promote an icon into the notification area as a short preview (under one minute).* Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx